# incorporating css3 column-count in a page section isn't working

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hi everyone I've tested and tried the css and code but still can't get it working on this page:

http://www.beauty-courses-distance-learning.co.uk/aromatherapy-self-use-wellbeing.html

I'm trying to add a css3 column-count to the links list towards the bottom "Other courses you may be interested in" but despite adding column-count it's not showing up/working and the list still goes down the page as normal.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In CSS2, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-); they cannot start with
>   a hyphen or a digit. They can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier “B&W?” may be written as “B\&W\?” or “B\26 W\3F”.

Your `.2coltext` class is starting with a digit and as such is not being picked up. Try removing the number from the class and it should work fine.

```
.coltext {
  -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
   column-count:2;
}
```

Comment: Wow fantastic, I completely missed the digit. Thank you very much it's now fixed the issue!

Comment: @Madrid1980 Awesome!! I'm glad. If the answer fixed your issue please make sure to mark it as such by ticking the arrow next to my answer to close this thread.